# What is the intended replacement for the Jersey inflector when upgrading to jersey 2?

Tags: java, jersey

This class is now gone:

```
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.Inflector
```

And the only mention of an Inflector I can find, in Jersey 2, is this interface:

```
public interface Inflector<DATA, RESULT> {
    public RESULT apply(DATA data);
}
```

Has the old inflector been pulled into a separate package?